# Freeze in Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, freeze, regex-lookarounds

My computer is Windows 7 using the last Python version (**3.6.4**)

I've got a freeze (or hangup) in Python with a simple regular expression.

For didatic reasons, I've cut the excess and the code is:

```
import re
p = r'^\s*if(?:[^)]+(?!\)\s+[a-z]))*[^)]+\)\s+[a-z]'  # raw string
c = re.compile(p,re.I)   # It's OK. I've tried it. 
s = r'if ( slots[pass[i]].indexOf(passRight[i])==-1 )  // ahk comment'
r = c.search(s)  # regular expression running. Hangup
print(r)  # Never arrive here
```

The regular expression `p` skips the spaces, then `IF`, so it skips non `)` chars until (using look ahead feature) occur a ')' followed by  spaces and a letter. That situation does not occur in the two `)` in the string `s`, so it  never match that situation, that is invalid in `AutoHotKey` language.

So the right running it will return no match

However, I have an ugly infinite loop.

I repeat the same test in interactive mode using `IDLE'. It's the same!

It's very weird.

Can somebody help me?

**UPDATE**

Below the perfect answer from [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew). It's place like a comment but should be here as an answer. It saves my day!:

*"[Remove + After [^)]](https://regex101.com/r/YhbrNs/1) or the regex engine will try too many paths to match the same text that does not finally match, causing a catastrophic backtracking. The `(?:[^)]+(?!\)\s+[a-z]))*` is just a pattern of the `(a+)+` type that will cause CB when used in the middle of the pattern. See more examples [here](https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking) and [this one, too](https://snyk.io/blog/redos-and-catastrophic-backtracking/)."*

The last link from Wiktor comment is particularly elucidative. Below `patt` is a simple regex, and it works for small strings. However, for large string it's painful.

```
patt = r'A(B|C+)+D'
```

The right way. No ambiguity. No inner and outer repeater:

```
patt = r'A(B|C)+D'
```

In this case, the fault is somewhat obvious. My above example is a little bit more subtle, because non `)` char is much more common than ')', even so, the internal `+` is still useless.

So, it's just cut the inner `+`. If `[^)]+` changes to `[^)]` and everything works great:

```
p = r'^\s*if(?:[^)](?!\)\s+[a-z]))*[^)]+\)\s+[a-z]'  # raw string
```

I will try to be smarter next time.

Comment: what are you trying to find exactly, what is the expected output

Comment: It's prolly because of your catastrophic backtracking here `(?:[^)]+(?!\)\s+[a-z]))*`. You have multiple repetitions within a group that can be repeated

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html for details

Comment: I will see the reference. I'm writing an utility for seach  in a file for  any undiscovered syntax errors. In this case, it's forbiden the syntax "If (expressão) command" in the same line. The command always start with a letter.

Comment: Most lines run without any problem. That is line 271 of my source code.

Comment: NLA = (?!\)\s+[a-z])) - this negative look ahead pattern matches a ")" + spaces + letter. 

([^)]+ NLA )* - 1 or more non ")" chars  + NLA repeat 0 or more times. 

In the end, I mach the syntax error:
Sequence Non ")" + spaces + letter

Comment: There is no look behind and the internal nested expression uses "+", so it always advances if there are some partial match. No loop is possible. The external expression uses "*", but no problem because "0"matches indicates that after 1 or more non ")" chars, the search finds a ")" + spaces + letter, there is an undetected syntax error in AutoHotKey

Comment: [Remove `+` after `[^)]`](https://regex101.com/r/YhbrNs/1), or the regex engine will try too many paths to match the same text that does not finally match, causing a catastrophic backtracking. The `(?:[^)]+(?!\)\s+[a-z]))*` is just a pattern of the `(a+)+` type that will cause CB when used in the middle of the pattern. See more examples [here](https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking). And [this one, too](https://snyk.io/blog/redos-and-catastrophic-backtracking/).

Comment: Are you absolutely right. When I remove "+" as you suggest, it works as expected. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: I've updated my question. The problem was solved. I understand that it's not an infinite loop but the old regex had too many possibilities to run in a realistic period.

Now my 3.500 source code lines run smoothly